# Unable to set null to autoscale in cosmosdb ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am creating cosmos DB using ARM template.in that my collection may or maynot have autoscale settings for the one which has autoscale I want to set autoscale max throughputfor others I want to enter standard throughput. when my throughput is null the template picks the maxthroughput but when the autoscale max through put is null, it throws it's not able to convert to integer.

here is the working one:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
  "apiVersion": "2021-04-15",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'), parameters('collection1Name'))]",
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "id": "[parameters('collection1Name')]"
    },
    "options": {
       "throughput": null,
      "autoscaleSettings": {
        "maxThroughput": "4000"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('accountName_var'))]"
  ]
},
```

This one doesnt work

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
  "apiVersion": "2021-04-15",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'), parameters('collection2Name'))]",
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "id": "[parameters('collection2Name')]"
    },
    "options": {
       "throughput": 400,
      "autoscaleSettings": {
        "maxThroughput": null
      }
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('accountName_var'))]"
  ]
}
```

though both are integers first one works and second one is not. I am not able to use condition to not to execute the autoscale settings as well. the reason I want both to present is that I am planning to run the copy to run it for multiple collection creation which can have both (manual and autoscale configuration)
I have used this [quickstart](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.documentdb/cosmosdb-mongodb-autoscale/azuredeploy.json) template as the reference.

Comment: The quickstart does exactly what you asked for. Use the parameters, variables and the json that is in the options from the original quickstart template and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `autoscalesettings` into a dedicated variable and conditionally include that in the template depending on your parameters.

Full example: https://mattfrear.com/2020/06/17/conditionally-specify-a-property-in-an-arm-template/

Rough sketch on how this could look like (probably contains some small errors).

```json
{
    "parameters": {
        "enableAutoscale": {
            "type": "bool"
        }
        // other parameters
    },
    "variables": {
        "autoscaleSettings": {
            "maxThroughput": "[parameters('maxThroughput')]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections",
          "apiVersion": "2021-04-15",
          "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'), parameters('collection2Name'))]",
          "properties": {
            "resource": {
              "id": "[parameters('collection2Name')]"
            },
            "options": {
               "throughput": null, // probably similar if/else-logic
               "autoscaleSettings": "[if(parameters('enableAutoscale'), json('null'), variables('autoscaleSettings'))]"
            }
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases', variables('accountName_var'), parameters('databaseName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('accountName_var'))]"
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```